# CSS Parallelogram with Text

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I've made a parallelogram using CSS3's `skew` transform, and placed text within another div that has an opposite `skew` value so that the text remains un-transformed: **[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Enijar/jm1wqemL/)**.

Is there a way to have the text aligns to the edges of the parallelogram like this:

[image]

I'm open to other suggestions, such as using the `canvas` if it's not possible using CSS. If there is a JavaScript technique to do this then any links that may be useful would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** After hunting for some cross-browser solutions, the easiest tool I found to achieve this was with **[this tool](http://www.csstextwrap.com/)**.

Comment: I think you should try rotating the text as: http://jsfiddle.net/jm1wqemL/1/

Comment: @VickyGonsalves - the problem with that is that it's clearly skewed the content too

Comment: @DeeMac great find! Could you put that into an answer for other people who are looking for the same thing as me? I had a frustrating few hours trying different search terms and nothing useful came up.

Comment: That link in the updated question is not working any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested, your answer lies in the use of `-webkit-shape-inside`: http://hongkiat.com/blog/css3-content-wrapping

Define a `polygon` with the points that match your parallelogram and your content will fit that shape.

*TIP: To get the 'points' of your shape, export it as a vector from suitable graphics design software and in the SVG will be the coordinates.*

Comment: While this works, I would add that there is currently only limited browser support for `shape-inside`.

Comment: CSS shapes are supported by 91% of browsers as of 2019, no IE/Edge/Opera Mini support but are supported for most sane browser versions. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes